# What is the reason why virtual technology is not enabled in the bios of windows 7?

Tags: windows

I recently had to enable VT for windows7 since I want to run ubuntu on vmware so I was wondering why isnt it enabled by default is it some kind of security issue or just not necessary for the average user?

Comment: Why an OS is configured a certain way by default is not a programming question, making it off-topic here. You're looking for [su] instead. The guidelines for the types of question that are appropriate here can be found in the [help].

Comment: The BIOS belongs to the PC, by the way, not to Windows.  The default settings are determined by the PC manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several reasons, including "security" and "performance":

- https://superuser.com/questions/291340/why-do-pc-manufacturers-disable-advanced-cpu-features-in-the-bios-by-default
- http://www.vmware.com/pdf/asplos235_adams.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Intel virtualization technology can get hardware intensive and although the software requirement is low (Windows Vista) only modern CPUs made by INTEL ONLY such as Intel i7 support it.

Not all windows computers have an Intel CPU though (a good amount of them do). The only people that use the VTX technology are developers and people who want to run a different operating system than their computer came with, so not everyone. As for security issue, I'm not sure but it can get very RAM intensive. (i.e. the Android HAXM for developers has a default RAM usage of 2GB, and the minimum is 512 MB!).

If you want to know more you can check out [this article](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-intel-virtualization-technology/263)
or the website:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/virtualization/virtualization-technology/intel-virtualization-technology.html